# Javascript Populate list from REST

Tags: javascript, forms, list, rest

I am new to JS but have had some success using the ESRI API to make some web map applications.  I am now attempting to step into an application that is going to require some pure JS and am looking for advice on what method to use.  I want to create a drop list of unique values contained within a field from a REST data source.  Once the user clicks on a  value in the list, that value would be passed to a definition query on the REST to display only that data.  I am fine with the definition query, but how do I get started with creating the list and collecting the selected value to pass to the query.  Any help or assistance is greatly appreciated

Comment: Post the format of the data as it comes back from your data source. Im assuming it's JSON format

Comment: you need to read, learn, write some code, do some testing and once you stuck with a specific problem, you could ask here. but not before that. not when you have not spent any time on it figuring yourself.

Comment: I have tried to look at this myself and have explored the forms and lists, but i don't even know if I am looking at the correct things.

Comment: Have you looked into JQuery at all?  That will probably be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into some client-side templating engines like mustache, handlebars, etc.  You can run a template method against your json data and then append the result into the dom anywhere you like.